# variable inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this loop

```
for( i=1; i < 65; i++){

  $('#peperszmit1 #tabs-1 #checkBoxHolder').append('<div class="individualCheckbox"><input     type="checkbox" id="checkBoxik'+i+'" name="game1" /> HERE.. </div>');

}
```

and where it says HERE.. i would like to display value of i . If i just write i inside the div i get 65 checkboxes with "i" next to them. I would like to have a number instead.

Thanks!

Comment: You already know how to do it. Do the same as here: `'(...) id="checkBoxik'+i+'" name="game1" (...)'` .

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#peperszmit1 #tabs-1 #checkBoxHolder').append('<div class="individualCheckbox"><input     type="checkbox" id="checkBoxik'+i+'" name="game1" />' + i + '</div>')
```

Like this ?

Or did I get your question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#peperszmit1 #tabs-1 #checkBoxHolder').append(' HERE.. ' + i);
```

should work.

Also, note that `$('#peperszmit1 #tabs-1 #checkBoxHolder')` means "the single element called `checkBoxHolder` within the single element called `tabs-1` within the single element called `peperszmit1` which is rather redundant.  If `$("#checkBoxHolder')` does not specify a single element, you are using IDs wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `+` operator in order to **concatenate** two strings or a string and variable.

```
$('#peperszmit1 #tabs-1 #checkBoxHolder')
  .append('<div class="individualCheckbox">' +
          '<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxik' + i +
                 '" name="game1" /> ' + i + ' </div>');
```

And your code will also fit to narrow code-boxes like here in SO ;)